# Get the String representation of a variable name

Tags: apex

Is there a way through Apex to get the String-name of a variable?  I would like something like:

```
String varName = Opportunity.StageName.name;
or
String varName = <method>(Opportunity.StageName);
```

I want to be able to pass back a list of Strings of variables that have changed within a Trigger.

Comment: By variable, do you mean field within a record? And by string-name, do you mean the label?

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes and yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a field's token, you can get its label. There's a few ways to get a token.

## Static

If you know which field you want in advance, you can use a static describe. That looks like this:

```
String fieldLabel = Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe().getLabel();
```

## Dynamic

If you don't know which field you want, you can describe all fields, iterate through the list, and select the ones you want:

```
Map<String, SObjectField> fields = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

The "string" key of "fields", above, will contain the API name of the fields, while the SObjectField is a token that you can use to describe a field (as the first example).

Note that you are limited to 100 field describes per transaction, so you should make some attempt to cache them using a map.